# Most pythonic way to collect warnings from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a very simple function:

```
def generate_something(data):
    if data is None:
        raise Exception('No data!')

    return MyObject(data)
```

Its output is basically an instance of an object I want to create or an exception if the function cannot create the object. We can say that the output is *binary* since it either succeeds (and gives back an object) or not (and gives back an Exception).

What is the most pythonic way to handle a third state, that is "success but with some warnings"?

```
def generate_something(data):
    warnings = []

    if data is None:
        raise Exception("No data!")

    if data.value_1 == 2:
        warnings.append('Hmm, value_1 is 2')    

    if data.value_2 == 1:
        warnings.append('Hmm, value_2 is 1')    

    return MyObject(data), warnings
```

Is returning a tuple the only way to handle this, or it is possible to *broadcast* or yield warnings from within the functions and catch them from the caller?

Comment: FWIW there's [`warnings.warn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn), but I don't think that's the kind of warning mechanism you're looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what is inadequate with Python's standard `warnings` module as Aran suggests? Without that information, I consider the question unclear

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with the wording module, but if I want a list of warnings, that's not what I'm getting from it. It writes to stderror, doesn't return a list of warnings.

Comment: This is just vague speculation. But if I encountered such a scenario where a function needs to report a lot of state information, I would wonder if the function is doing too much, or not enough. That is (a) is it possible to split it into "atomic" operations that always result in success or failure? Or (b) how do callers need to handle various states, and is it possible to encapsulate that behavior into the function itself so the states don't matter upstream?

Comment: Addendum: This last comment assumes that the caller actually needs the state information during normal operation. If they don't, and it's just "nice to have" for diagnostics, you might want to use a debug flag, or possibly accumulate the warnings in a list passed in as an optional keyword argument. Then the caller can use the function without caring about the warnings, while putting them in the return value forces them to explicitly destructure the return value.

Answer (score 6):

#### The built-on option: [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html)

Python has a built-in warning mechanism implemented in the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module. The problem with this is that `warnings` maintains a global [warnings filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter), which might unintenionally cause the warnings your function throws to be suppressed. Here's a demonstration of the problem:

```
import warnings

def my_func():
    warnings.warn('warning!')

my_func()  # prints "warning!"

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
my_func()  # prints nothing
```

If you want to use `warnings` regardless of this, you can use [`warnings.catch_warnings(record=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) to collect all thrown warnings in a list:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warning_list:
    warnings.warn('warning 3')

print(warning_list)  # output: [<warnings.WarningMessage object at 0x7fd5f2f484e0>]
```

#### The self-made option

For the reason explained above, I recommend rolling your own warning mechanism instead. There are various ways to implement this:

- **Just return a list of warnings**

  The easiest solution with the least overhead: Just return the warnings.

  ```
  def example_func():
      warnings = []

      if ...:
          warnings.append('warning!')

      return result, warnings

  result, warnings = example_func()
  for warning in warnings:
      ...  # handle warnings
  ```
- **Pass a warning handler to the function**

  If you want to handle the warnings immediately when they're generated, you can rewrite your function to accept a warning handler as argument:

  ```
  def example_func(warning_handler=lambda w: None):
      if ...:
          warning_handler('warning!')

      return result


  def my_handler(w):
      print('warning', repr(w), 'was produced')

  result = example_func(my_handler)
  ```

- **[`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) (python 3.7+)**

  With python 3.7 we got the [`contextvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) module, which lets us implement a higher-level warning mechanism based on context managers:

  ```
  import contextlib
  import contextvars
  import warnings


  def default_handler(warning):
      warnings.warn(warning, stacklevel=3)

  _warning_handler = contextvars.ContextVar('warning_handler', default=default_handler)


  def warn(msg):
      _warning_handler.get()(msg)


  @contextlib.contextmanager
  def warning_handler(handler):
      token = _warning_handler.set(handler)
      yield
      _warning_handler.reset(token)
  ```

  Usage example:

  ```
  def my_warning_handler(w):
      print('warning', repr(w), 'was produced')

  with warning_handler(my_warning_handler):
      warn('some problem idk')  # prints "warning 'some problem idk' was produced"

  warn(Warning('another problem'))  # prints "Warning: another problem"
  ```

  **Caveats:** As of now, `contextvars` doesn't support generators. (Relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0568/).) Things like the following example won't work correctly:

  ```
  def gen(x):
      with warning_handler(x):
          for _ in range(2):
              warn('warning!')
              yield

  g1 = gen(lambda w: print('handler 1'))
  g2 = gen(lambda w: print('handler 2'))

  next(g1)  # prints "handler 1"
  next(g2)  # prints "handler 2"
  next(g1)  # prints "handler 2"
  ```

- **without `contextvars` (for python <3.7)**

  If you don't have `contextvars`, you can use this async-unsafe implementation instead:

  ```
  import contextlib
  import threading
  import warnings


  def default_handler(warning):
      warnings.warn(warning, stacklevel=3)

  _local_storage = threading.local()
  _local_storage.warning_handler = default_handler


  def _get_handler():
      try:
          return _local_storage.warning_handler
      except AttributeError:
          return default_handler


  def warn(msg):
      handler = _get_handler()
      handler(msg)


  @contextlib.contextmanager
  def warning_handler(handler):
      previous_handler = _get_handler()
      _local_storage.warning_handler = handler

      yield

      _local_storage.warning_handler = previous_handler
  ```

Comment: Although the `contextvars` example is fascinating, [everyone probably just wants to use **warning replaying** instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77516994/2809027). I'm unclear whether @NikoFohr discovered this technique or not – but he now deserves all the credit, because I've never seen this anywhere else. It turns out you can reissue multiple previously issued warnings just like you can reraise a single previously raised exception. Combine `warnings.catch_warnings(record=True)` (which records all issued warnings) with `warnings.warn_explicit()` (which replays a previously issued warning).

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list of `Exceptions` (or custom exceptions) with the problems for later handling:

```
class MyWarning(Warning):
    pass

def generate_something(data):
    warnings = []
    if data is None:
        raise Exception("No data!")

    if data.value_1 == 2:
        warnings.append(MyWarnin('Hmm, value_1 is 2'))    

    if data.value_2 == 1:
        warnings.append(MyWarning('Hmm, value_2 is 1'))    

    return MyObject(data), warnings
```

And then for example:

```
def handle_warnings(warnings):
    for w in warnings:
        try:
            raise w
        except MyWarning:
            ...
        except AttributeError: #in case you want to handle other type of errors
            ...
```

Comment: sub-classing `Warning` would make more sense