# Python: Catching (and then re-throw) warnings from my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

I want to catch and then re-throw warnings from my Python code, similarly to `try`/`except` clause. My purpose is to catch the warning and then re-throw it using my logger.

The warnings are issued from whatever packages I'm using, I would like something that is totally generic, exactly like the `try`/`except` clause.

How can I do that in Python >= v3.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to tackle this:

1. Record the warnings and replay them
2. Make warnings to behave like exceptions and break the control flow

#### Option 1: Record warnings and replay them

You could use [warnings.catch_warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) with `record=True` to record the Warning objects. This way all your application code will get executed regardless of any warnings.

```py
import warnings
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class NotImportantWarning(UserWarning):
    ...


def do_something():
    warnings.warn("doing something", UserWarning)
    warnings.warn("This is not important", NotImportantWarning)


# Executing our main function and recording warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as recorded_warnings:
    do_something()

print("done")

# Handling warnings. You may log it here.
for w in recorded_warnings:
    if isinstance(w.message, NotImportantWarning):
        continue

    # re-issue warning
    warnings.warn_explicit(
        message=w.message,
        category=w.category,
        filename=w.filename,
        lineno=w.lineno,
        source=w.source,
    )
    # or use a logger
    logger.warning(str(w.message))
```

This will print then something like

```
done
<ipython-input-6-cc898056d044>:12: UserWarning: doing something
  warnings.warn("doing something", UserWarning)
doing something
```

#### Notes

- Using the lower level [warnings.warn_explicit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn_explicit) to re-issue the warnings. The denefit over `warnings.warn` is that with the `warn_explicit` it is possible to retain the original filename and line number information.

#### Option 2: Make warnings to behave like exceptions

If you really want to break the control flow right at the warning, like with exceptions, it is possible with `warnings.filterwarnings("error")`:

```py
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('error')


try:
    do_something()
except UserWarning as w:
    print(w)
```

Note: The code execution stops at the first warning. No code inside `do_something` after that warning will ever get executed.

Comment: **Option 2** is *basically* useless. Interrupting flow control defeats the point of using warnings in the first place. But **Option 1**... *ohmygods*. Did you invent this? Because this is ingenious. Replaying multiple previously issued warnings is an analogue to re-raising a single previously raised exception – and it's only *slightly* more cumbersome. I'm currently leveraging this boss technique throughout [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype), where low-level functions raise warnings with placeholder messages that high-level functions then "catch," modify, and replay. `\o/`

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I found about this but it was something I needed to do in some codebase :) I would guess I searched for answer, found this unanswered, read the warnings module documentation to find if there's anything that would help me, and came back to write it down here. Glad to hear it's helping beartype!